# Round-tripping activerecord queries through Arel with bound parameters

Tags: activerecord, arel

I'd like to better understand how ActiveRecord and Arel handle bound parameters for those cases when I need to use Arel to access SQL features not available in ActiveRecord, but don't want to entirely give up on the functionality I already have in ActiveRecord.

Often, this means doing something along these lines:

```
selectmanager = User.all.arel
# manipulate selectmanager with arel...
users = User.find_by_sql(selectmanager.to_sql)
```

While this works, there's a problem if the starting `ActiveRecord::Relation` isn't something trivial like `User.all`, but instead something that has bound parameters. When there are bound parameters, `selectmanager.to_sql` contains `$1` in place of the parameter, and examining the SelectManager's contents I see it contains an `Arel::Nodes::BoundParam`, and Postgres complains:

```
ERROR:  bind message supplies 0 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 1
```

Now, the bound values are somehow in the relation (I can see them with `the_relation.bound_attributes`) and AFAIK, ActiveRecord ultimately uses Arel to generate the query, so somewhere there's something that has all the values, knows how to match them up to the bound parameters, and pass this to the database. But that's lost when a Relation is converted to Arel with the technique above.

So, how can I start with an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, manipulate it with the full power of Arel (adding joins, unions, recursive CTEs, using wacky operators like `<@`, etc), then bring it back to the ActiveRecord world without losing bound parameters and values?

(At the moment I'm using ActiveRecord 5.0, and Arel 7.1, but knowing something that works for any version would help.)

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "bring it back to `ActiveRecord`"? Are you referring to using `find_by_sql` (which is essentially SELECT * FROM table WHERE conditions)

Comment: @engineersmnky what to use is the question. I want to get a Relation or at least some collection of ApplicationRecord as a result, as if I had done the query through normal ActiveRecord query methods, but I want to build the query with Arel so I'm not limited in the kind of queries I can make.

Comment: can you post a conceptual example? I am on your team, `Arel` is an amazing library. I have never tried to go about it the way you are suggesting so I would be glad to give it a go although it is going to take some deep diving. That being said in regards to the bind parameters the method that handles this `to_sql_and_binds` is a private method in the adapter. Pass in arel and it returns an Array of [sql_string, bind_parameters]

Comment: Besides the example already in the question, what could I provide?

Comment: There may be better avenues but the most direct version I can find is `User.find_by_sql(*ActiveRecord::Base.connection.send(:to_sql_and_binds, SELECT_MANAGER_HERE))` which should work. That being said `find_by_sql` returns an `Array` so you could also capture the SQL and binds and use `exec_query`. e.g. `sql,binds =ActiveRecord::Base.connection.send(:to_sql_and_binds, SELECT_MANAGER_HERE); ActiveRecord::Base.exec_query(sql,"SQL",binds).map { |user| User.new(user)}`